# Server Error 413 on gridview update

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview (asp.net) that allows the user to fill in some text boxes and submit the data to the server (SQL Server 2005, Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0) and if the user has a lot of data to submit, I am starting to get hit with

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 413
```

errors.  Is there an IIS setting that I can update to allow for max data to be sent back and forth?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, if I run the application on my localhost, I do not get the error which is leading me to believe that the production server has an IIS setting that is breaking this upload.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the setting for `UploadReadAheadSize` is the key to your problem. There are several ways to adjust this setting, all detailed in [HTTP 413 Request Entity too large in IIS 6 and 7](http://tmoaikel.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/http-413-request-entity-too-large-in-iis-6-and-7/)

Comment: I have updated the UploadReadAheadSize to the max allowed via IIS and I am still receiving the error.